# How to remove tags inside tag in PHP?

Tags: php, html, regex

I'm a newbie in regex , i tried to get content from a website , but sometime content in websitelook like this . Ex1:

```
<strong> text </strong><strong><a href="" target="_blank"> text </a> text</strong>
```

sometime looklike this ,Ex2:

```
<strong> text <a target="_blank" href=""> text </a> text </strong>
```

Now i stuck on this , if the content look like Ex2, I can get all the content . but if the content look like Ex1 , I just get the content of first strong tags . How can I get all content like Ex 2?

Comment: Don't use regexp for parsing HTML, use an HTML parser library.

Comment: RegEx is not adequate to parse HTML.

Comment: That's a trivial task, and contrary to popular opinion suitable for a regex (closing tag immediately followed by opening one, not nested) even if you're inexperienced. The question is, if you've picked that solution due to cursory reseach finding similar examples online, why didn't you try something out before reposting it as coding request?

Comment: share what have you tried?

Comment: How about php `strip_tags()` function to clean the html tags - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: I use strip_tags already ,  if html construct look like ex2 ,i will get all text , but if contruct look like ex1 , it just get <strong> text </strong>

Answer (score 0):

Use [Document Object Model](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) as suggested by others if still you want to look into regex then it's very simple regex pattern using *Lazy* way:

Get the matched group from index 1.

```
<strong>(.*?)<\/strong>
```

Here is [demo](http://regex101.com/r/lP9aI4/1)

sample code:

```
$re = "/<strong>(.*?)<\\/strong>/";
$str = "<strong> text </strong><strong><a href=\"\" target=\"_blank\"> text </a> text</strong>";

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

> I just get the content of first strong tags

You might using `preg_match`